# Throwing "Could not load type NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule" after upgrading NLog.Extended from 2.0 to 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nlog

My MVC 5 application running on .net framework 4.6 and previously it has Nlog.Extended 2.0.
and it was running smoothly.

Now, I want to update the Nlog.extended version with the latest version 4.6.6. While upgrading it upto 3.2.1 it is working fine, but when I upgrade it to 4 and above version, it is throwing runtime error "Could not load type 'NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule' from assembly 'NLog.Extended'. ". Please fellow attached error screen shot.
Please help me to fixed this error.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From NLog.Extended version 4, according to NLog [documentation](https://nlog-project.org/2015/05/28/nlog-4-release-candidate.html), there are breaking changes.
NLog.Exntended and Nlog.Web are splitted. 
The class you are trying to load is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web/).

See [github page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web) to configure it properly:
The NLogHttpModule needs a registration in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer> 
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
    <add name="NLog" type="NLog.Web.NLogHttpModule, NLog.Web" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks  for the help it is working.. Actually due to Split of the package NLog.Extended to NLog.Web and NLog.Windows.Forms